# Why does the gui work on Mac but malfunctions on Windows?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I have a gui windows created and I am setting audio to play when it is called on. When I run the code in Mac, I have no problems with the GUI. My title panel and button panel appear while my music plays.

When I run the code on Windows, the music will begin to play in the gui window, but my title and button panel disappear and I can't progress forward.

I appreciate any and all input.

```
public static void setWindow() {
        window.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1280, 719));
        window.setResizable(false);
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        window.setContentPane(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(Objects.requireNonNull(ExploreMissionScreenHandler.class.getClassLoader().getResource("StuckInSpace.jpg")))));
        window.setLayout(null);
        window.setVisible(true);
        window.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        playMusic(0);
        window.pack();
    }
```

```
    public static void playMusic(int i) {
        sound.setFile(i);
        sound.play();
        sound.loop();
    }
```

Comment: What does the `playMusic` method look like?

Comment: window.setLayout(null); isn’t helping the situation

Comment: @Jesper I added it to my original post

Comment: Thank you @MadProgrammer. I was wondering about that, but my friend said I needed that there.

Comment: [mcve] please ..

Comment: `pack()` should come before `setVisible(true)` though it makes no sense here. Instead of overriding the `PreferredSize` and calling `pack()`, it would be simpler to just use `setSize(1280, 719)` and not to call `pack()` at all. Besides that, it’s not clear which “title and button panel” you’re talking about as all that the code does, is open a window with a picture (`JLabel` with `ImageIcon`). There are no titles nor button panels.